# std::vector reserve method fails to allocate enough memory

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management, segmentation-fault, stdvector

I have a buffer class in my C++ application as follows:

```
class Buffer
{
    public:
    Buffer(size_t res): _rpos(0), _wpos(0)
    {
        _storage.reserve(res);
    }

    protected:
    size_t _rpos, _wpos;
    std::vector<uint8> _storage;
}
```

Sometimes using the constructor fails because its unable to allocate the required memory space. For example, once,  calling the constructor with `res = 37` caused a segfault with the following stack trace that i got from its core dump:

```
#0  0x00007f916a176ed5 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00007f916a1783f3 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00007f916a1b33a8 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00007f916a1b8948 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00007f916a1bb17c in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00007f916a1bca78 in malloc () from /lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00007f916ac0c16d in operator new (sz=37)
    at ../../.././libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/new_op.cc:52
        p = <value optimized out>
#7  0x00000000004e3d11 in std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::reserve (this=0x7f911bc49cc0, __n=31077)
    at /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.4.2/../../../../include/c++/4.4.2/ext/new_allocator.h:89
        __old_size = 0
        __tmp = <value optimized out>
```

I've compiled this application using GCC 4.4.2 as a 64 bit application and I'm using it in Debian 5 x64.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The trace definetly shows that res = 31077, not 37 as you claim. It is still small (for 64 bit system at least), but you are probably looking in wrong place for a fault. Can you show frames 8 and above from backtrace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't use Valgrind to find out where your memory is corrupted because of the heavy load it implies, you can still test with lighter solutions.

For server application where Valgrind was not applicable (because the platform was on Solaris 8), I had pretty good result with mpatrol ( http://mpatrol.sf.net ) but especially dmalloc ( http://dmalloc.com ).

To some extend, you can use them without recompiling (just relinking for dmalloc, library preloading for mpatrol). They'll replace the memory primitives to perform extra checks on the memory use (bad argument to those primitives, reading off-by-one, heap corruption, ...) Some of those checks will be triggered exactly when the problem occurs while others will be triggered a bit later than the actual bad code. By tuning which checks are enabled, and when applicable the check frequency, you can run at almost full speed while performing basic checks.

I recommend recompiling with dmalloc to get so called 'FUNC_CHECK', for me, this added a lot of accuracy in bug spotting with a negligible performance cost.

Answer (score 8):

Because the segfault is in malloc, most likely some other code has trashed the heap (i.e. written to parts of memory they do not own and are being used by the heap manager).

I recommend using [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to find what code is trashing the heap.

Comment: I can't use Valgrind for this application since its a server application and is under heavy load. Valgrind makes it so slow that it becomes almost useless. As a result the segfault wont ever happen. Unfortunately i need a solution other than Valgrind to find the cause. Maybe something i can implement in the application to find the cause for me.

Comment: @Martin York: In case you haven't noticed, I'm trying to learn to write code without any errors by asking others to guide me find my mistake.

Comment: In case you hadn't noticed, Martin York just guided you in finding your mistake. ;)

Run valgrind on another machine. Ultimately, you don't have a lot of options. *Somewhere* in the process, some piece of code corrupts the heap *somehow* and at *some* time before this segfault occurred. As Martin York said, you only have two options: 1) write code that doesn't contain bugs such as these, or 2) run diagnostic tools *such as Valgrind* to help you find the bug that is there.